# How to automate release notes using GIT merge descriptions

Tags: node.js, automation, gitlab, gitops

All,

In our organization we are trying to automate generating RELEASE NOTES using GIT Merge requests.
Is there any better way to do this, preferably looking for a solution in NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

When using something like `standard-version` and `commitizen` for standardization of your commits you can make use of a GitLab CI-Pipeline that generates your release notes based on the changelog that is generated by `standard-version`

Within this [Repository](https://gitlab.com/uulmhack/boilerplates/react-typescript-application-starterkit) the project was set up using `nodejs`, `react` and `typescript`, but the configuration would be the same.
This [CI-Configuration](https://gitlab.com/uulmhack/boilerplates/react-typescript-application-starterkit/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml#L18-48) is an example of the aforementioned pipeline configuration.

The same thing would also be applicable for Github actions with a little modification for Github-specific action syntax.

##### Without CI-Pipeline

The same thing would also be applicable for non-CI setups since the commands used in the ci-configuration are as well executable in local machines, but that way you would have some manual effort

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the semantic release plugin for GitLab: https://github.com/semantic-release/gitlab

Which implements the popular https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release project.